# How to update a field using alias in mysql?

Tags: mysql, alias, sql-update

I am having a table in mysql, and in that i am having two fields that is id and desc, now as desc is a mysql keyword, i am unable to update that field because mysql is giving syntax error, so i thought why not update that field by using alias, i used it but not working, is there any way to update that field using alias.
Please help! I need it very badly.
Thanks
Ravinder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with:

```
UPDATE t1 SET `desc`='NEW VAL'
```

Notice the single backquotes ( ` ) around the `desc` field name